# Java Applet For Loop - Cant seem to close it out correctly

Tags: java, graphics, applet, paint

I am trying to create a Java Applet for a school assignment. I have a for loop in my paint method that is responsible for drawing the number of ovals that is entered by the user. I have been attempting to find the correct way to format because I have been getting compiling errors each time I try to fix the errors the compiler sends back to me.

The paint method I currently have is as follows:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)

{
    
super.paint(g);

g.setColor(Color.blue);

int inc=0,len=0;

for (int i=0;

    
g.drawOval(20+inc, 20+inc, 25+len, 25+len);

inc=inc+3;

len=len+5;


}
```

The final outcome of the applet for my assignment is supposed to draw a series of ovals. I am also having trouble finding a good resource that explains how to display an applet using a small HTML file, but that is for another post.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: `for (initial condition; termination condition; change condition) { ... }` - you should start by having a look at [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).  Also, applets are no longer supported, you shouldn't be wasting time with them - and you school shouldn't be wasting time with them

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm afraid many schools are using outdated material to teach. Only yesterday I had such a discussion with somebody who had to follow a course of awt programming for his degree

Comment: @Stultuske Yea, I'm a computer information systems major, we have now spent almost HALF of the semester learning java.awt and all the different methods for applets. I will not be leaving the most kind course review when it ends.

Comment: @Stultuske Well isn't that just useless - I'd be questioning the value of the course

Comment: Started The Odin Project today, and I can tell external resources will teach me much more valuable things than school will ever. Deadlines and due dates do not provide the best learning environment for aspiring developers

Comment: @MadProgrammer indeed. He was supposed to code AWT code in Android Studio ..talking about an odd combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)

{
    
super.paint(g);

g.setColor(Color.blue);

int inc=0,len=0;

for(int i=0;i

{
    
g.drawOval(20+inc, 20+inc, 25+len, 25+len);

inc=inc+3

len=len+5

}

}
```

This was able to compile at least with no errors

Answer (score 0):

A `for-loop` has three components

- Initialisation
- Termination
- Change

These are separated by `;` and, if nothing is happening a component can be omitted, but that's a little more advanced.

So, you need to describe;

- Where you want to start
- When you want to stop
- And what you want to change on each loop

These conditions need to be expressed in simple terms

`for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {...}` which basically says, initialise `i` to `0`, while `i` is less then `100`, add `1` to `i` and do what ever is in `{...}` on each loop

So, at a very basic level, your loop might look something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    g.drawOval(20 + inc, 20 + inc, 25 + len, 25 + len);
    inc = inc + 3;
    len = len + 5;
}
```

Remember to always consult the [official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and other web resources first, looping is a very common operation and much has been written about it

Comment: Yes, certainly, this is a great explanation and I'm sure I didn't exhaust all my other options, but as you stated, it can become a bit more advanced when omitting one or multiple of the components, which is what my loop required (well, I'm sure there exists a more efficient, neater, and better way that utilizes all three). See below, if you wish, the answer I posted. That one at least compiled with no errors, but actually, I would love to see your feedback to that if you would be so kind!

Comment: I'm not too sure if I was aiming for an infinite loop because it is based off the user input, and I'm sure I should think more as to what I'm truly trying to accomplish. I always appreciate feedback of any kind, and your post is greatly appreciated as it still taught me about the foundations of for loops.